# Is the Cognitive Approach (SOAR) equivalent to the Chinese Room argument?

Tags: philosophy, cognitive-science, chinese-room-argument, cognitive-architecture, soar

Soar is a cognitive architecture.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soar_(cognitive_architecture)
- https://soar.eecs.umich.edu/

There is something called "the Chinese box" or "Chinese room" argument:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room
- https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/chinese-room/

The "Chinese room" seems to be begging its question, but that is not what I am asking.  I am asking if there is any literal difference between a tool like "SOAR" and the formalism of the "Chinese box".  Is SOAR identical or equivalent to a "Chinese Box"?

Comment: Interesting question. However, the question in the title seems to be slightly different than the question in the body. Maybe clarify this!

Answer (score 1):

Searle's Chinese room is analogical and is intended to present an easy-to-understand picture of the essential elements and processes of the digital computer. In the room the man (CPU) has a book of intructions (program) for responding to Chinese input questions. That is just one program of many possible programs the room could run. Each different program would be a different instruction book. SOAR would be just one of those books.

Comment: Yes, this seems reasonable, but I think you should say something about what SOAR is trying to do, i.e. is SOAR only manipulating symbols, etc.? I think this is the crux of the question.

Comment: I can emulate the hardware of a computer, on a computer.  In that emulation I can run a program.  If I wanted to be a little recursive the program itself could be emulation, arguably of much simpler hardware.  Together this system might comprise an inception-like box within a box within a box.  Can I understand your answer to mean that any computer is the Chinese box, an anti-Turing?